# Determine which fragment currently visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've `ViewPager` which I'm using for displaying few fragments, I also have `TextView` on my `FragmentActivity`. I need to change text in `TextView` depending on which fragment is currently selected in `ViewPager`. The problem I've faced: `ViewPager` have some caching mechanism, it instantiates fragments before they are really visible for user, for example when I select second page in `ViewPager` fragment on third page also created. What is more I can't determine inside fragment is this fragment visible now or it's just created by `ViewPager`, but not really visible for user. I've tryed to use `OnPageChangeListener` for this, but changes made in it was unacceptable slow for me(page scrolled and then my `TextView` have changed)
 
**What I actually need:** I need to determine which fragment is currently visible in `ViewPager`, no matter from `FragmentActivity` or from `Fragment` itself. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` is the obvious approach here. And as you have noticed, `onPageSelected(int position)` doesn't get called until the page is centered (if you are slowly scrolling the page by touch and holding on).

> What I actually need: I need to determine which fragment is currently visible in ViewPager, no matter from FragmentActivity or from Fragment itself. How can I achieve this?

First, you haven't defined "currently visible". In a `ViewPager`, 2 pages can both be seen while swiping between them, so which one is "currently visible" mid-swipe? My assumption is that you would consider whichever page is "more visible" to be "currently visible".

Having that said, I would look into using [`onPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled%28int,%20float,%20int%29). It appears that `positionOffset` may be able to give you the information you need. I would test it with some logging statements to see what data returns.