# Check if fragment is currently visible or no

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I know there are lots of similar questions in StackOverflow but my question is little different.

I have nested hierarchy of Fragments like in below structure:

```
                                  Activity
                                     |
                                     |
                                 AFragment
                                     |
                                (ViewPager)
                                 |       |         
                                 |       |         
                         BFragment       BFragment  .....
                            |                       
                       (ViewPager)                       
                        |       |                         
                        |       |                         
                 CFragment     CFragment  ...
                     |
                (ViewPager)                       
                  |     |                              
                  |     |                        
           DFragment   DFragment ...
```

Now i want to know that whether `DFragment` is showing to user or not?

I tried lots of solution from StackOverflow but couldn't get sucess.

**What i tried is:**

I tried `setUserVisibleHint()` but it returns `true`for multiple `DFragment` in above hierarchy which is a cause of `ViewPager`

I also tried from these links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323279/how-to-test-if-a-fragment-view-is-visible-to-the-user), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221195/determine-which-fragment-currently-visible-in-viewpager) and so on... but did not got actual solution.

Waiting for help. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

**Adapter Class**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: u can create an instance of the fragment and then check it

Comment: I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter to show Fragments using newInstance

Comment: link3 is working for me. Did you tried that?

Comment: dont create a new instance , make it singleton

Comment: @Krish ya i tried viewpager change listener but no luck

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: @quicklearner i think making singletone do not help. I think its the effect for viewpager which loads 2-3 fragments at once.

Comment: yes it loads next fragments

Comment: can u please post your view pager adapter class

Comment: I have update my question please check @quicklearner

Comment: @Viks onPageSelected method will give the position for your fragment. Give it a try

Comment: @AbidKhan ya you are right but I think its the effect for viewpager which loads 2-3 fragments at once.

Comment: Yes you are right. In ViewPager the Fragment that you see and the next to it is loaded. So in this case you can work using both `onPageSelected` and `setUserVisibleHint()` methods. The first to check if the page is selected and the second is to check the selected page is visible or not.

Comment: For instance you can work like `if (position == 0) {
         SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
   isVisible = fragment.isVisible()
   }`

Comment: @AbidKhan problem is getUserVisibleHint() returns true for multiple Fragments.

Comment: @Viks do you have access to that `ViewPager` with `DFragment`s? Or you also don't know when `CFragment` is visible?

Comment: @Viks, added an answer that I'm using in an application. Please try that.

Comment: all below answer are not working

Comment: @Viks Try my solution which is working for me.

Comment: @Viks do you have access to that ViewPager with DFragments? Or you also don't know when CFragment is visible? _(Apr 27 at 7:28)_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591019/5773037

Answer (score 27):

You can check, whether the `View` that fragment inflated is visible on the device's screen:

```
    Fragment fragment = ... // retrieve from `ViewPager`'s adapter.
    View fragmentRootView = fragment.getView();
    if (fragmentRootView != null && fragmentRootView.getGlobalVisibleRect(new Rect())) {
        // fragment is visible
    } else {
        // fragment is not visible
    }
```

[`getGlobalVisibleRect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point)) will return `true` if part of the view is visible at the root level.

Comment: In my case I am getting fragment visibility other way around using same code as you suggested. when fragment is visible it goes to else block and when its not visible its goes to If block.

Comment: there are cases when this solution wont work. alternatively, you can use `userVisibleHint`

Comment: I find that this seems to work well for fragments not in ViewPagers and only if you wrap the `getGlobalVisibleRect` call in in a post runnable i.e. `fragmentRootView.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { fragmentRootView.getGlobalVisibleRect(new Rect()))  }})`. The `setUserVisibleHint()` detect method works better for fragments in a ViewPager.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {

        }
        else
        {       

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try..

The `isVisible()` adds an extra layer of visibility check.

```
    ViewPager viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager); 

    final Fragment[] fragments={new DFragment(),new MyFragment()};  //add all the other fragment objects present in the view pager......

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(fragments[position].isVisible()){
                //Cool stuff to do.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `override` `setUserVisibleHint()` in each fragment where you want to check whether it is visible or not with a additional flag. For an example

Java:

```
boolean isVisited = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser && !isVisited ) 
    {
         isVisited = true;
    }
    else if(isVisited)
    {
        // this fragment is already in front of user
    }
}
```

I was having similar problem. Once I was need to load data from server to `fragment` only when it was in-front of user. I solved it as above.

Kotlin :

```
    private var isVisited: Boolean = false


    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isVisited!! )
        {
            isVisited = true;
        }
        else if(isVisited!!)
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Location required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you as well.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have tried I think this will work Please try and let me know. 
Do something like this in your activity.

---

```
public boolean isFragmentVisible(SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter) {
        SwipeAdapter swipeAdapterA = fragmentA.getViewPagerAdapter();
        BFragment bFragment = (BFragment) swipeAdapterA.getFragment(0);
        if (bFragment != null) {
            SwipeAdapter swipeAdapterB = bFragment.getViewPagerAdapter();
            CFragment cFragment = (CFragment) swipeAdapterA.getFragment(0);
            if (cFragment != null) {
                SwipeAdapter swipeAdapterC = cFragment.getViewPagerAdapter();
                DFragment dFragment = (DFragment) swipeAdapterA.getFragment(0);
                if (dFragment != null) {
                    return dFragment.isFragmentVisible();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Use this class as your viewpager adapter

```
  class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        private String mPagetile[];

        public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            mPagetile = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageTitle);
            mFragmentManager = fm;
            mFragmentTags = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new "Your_fragment";
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
                Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
                String tag = f.getTag();
                mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
            String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
            if (tag == null)
                return null;
            return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mPagetile[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return "Number of fragments";
        }
    }
```

Now in your DFragment do this

```
 boolean isVisible=false;

        @Override
        public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
            super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
            isVisible=menuVisible;
        }

        public boolean isFragmentVisible(){
            return isVisible;
        }
```

Let me know if it worked if not let me know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

We can easily map which fragment is now visible using `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()` method. This method gives `int` value number from which we can find the current fragment.

-- For access and get this method result we have two options:

1. make `Static` viewPager instance in activity and use wherever we
       want
2. again make `viewPager` instance in fragment (`findViewById()`)

and using one from above two methods `getCurrentItem()` in fragment to find which fragment is visible now.

For example,

1. In MainActivity (activity which is used for ViewPager)
   define

`public static ViewPager mViewPager;`

- In Fragment,  `MainActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem()` to get current fragment

Also, method that shows which fragment is visible:

```
public void whichIsVisible() {
    String msg = "";
    int curFragNo = MainActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    switch (curFragNo) {
        case 0:
            msg = "AFragment is visible.";
            break;
        case 1:
            msg = "BFragment is visible.";
            break;
        case 2:
            msg = "CFragment is visible.";
            break;
        case 3:
            msg = "DFragment is visible.";
            break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

(2)  For non-static use,

- get `viewPager` instance in fragment by below code,

`viewPager=(ViewPager) view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.container);`

and then

`viewPager.getCurrentItem()` to get index and find current visible fragment as per use.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that if you are trying to check while performing a scroll event (or when swiping and not releasing your finger), you'd see a part from neighbor fragment, but `whichIsVisible()` will return the previous fragment, whereas there are two visible currently.

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest sloution might be.
In `onCreate` of your `DF fragment` store a `boolean` in `preferences`. i.e `Key = is_fragment_visible_to_user` . And change it to `true`.
And in `onStop` or `onDestroy` (whichever fills your requirement) change, it's value to `false`. With this, you can check it easily by accessing the preferences value. In the case of multiple instances, you can store the tag with the another key.

Comment: This won't work, because `ViewPager` would create the fragment from left and right side (by default 1 at each side), which would mean that boolean would become `true`, but still fragment won't be displayed.

Comment: Have e heard about `onPageChangeListiner()` of `ViewPager` ?
Do you know this changeListiner provide the index of the current fragment? For example, If the first fragment it active index will be 0 and so on. So a simple check can be applied there as well. Hope you get it.

Comment: True it in onCreate and false it on pageChangeListiner. I wish it could be simpler than that.

Comment: Yes, **that** one may work, but it's roughly similar to the solution that Nitin Patel has provided. Nevertheless, I cannot see your current answer to work as expected.

Comment: It will work for you. With one or two extra checks. But no problem if you don't like this. But it's the simplest. Nitin answer is different, it will not tell u the first time when fragments are attached to the pager.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isFragmentVisible(Fragment fragment) {
    Activity activity = fragment.getActivity();
    View focusedView = fragment.getView().findFocus();
    return activity != null
            && focusedView != null
            && focusedView == activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findFocus();
}
```

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845274/2347486)

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem I solved it by using this hacky method 'going under the hood' like

Inside your `FragmentPagerAdapter`(s) add this function.

```
public Fragment getActiveFragment(ViewPager container, int position) {
        String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
        return fm.findFragmentByTag(name);
    }

    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
    }
```

It is not the most graceful solution but as long as it works

**CAUTION**

This is a private method internal to **ViewPager** that could change at any time or for any OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Although the past for so long, but I still want to give my program, because I found that get visible state of Fragment is indeed not easy. Based on your request, you need to solve these three questions:

- How to use FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter
- How to determine the visible state of Fragment
- How to handle when the Fragment is nested

At first, i defined a base Adapter help me to get the Fragment in ViewPager.If you Fragment's position and type is changeable in ViewPager, you must use  `public int getItemPosition(Object object)  method` and `public Fragment getItem(int position)` method to get the right position.

```
/**
 * Created by Kilnn on 2017/7/12.
 * A abstract FragmentStatePagerAdapter which hold the fragment reference.
 */
public abstract class SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

    public SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        WeakReference<Fragment> reference = registeredFragments.get(position);
        return reference != null ? reference.get() : null;
    }
}
```

At then ,i define a base Fragment to handle the visible state.But there is a little flaw is that you must specify same switch type for one set of fragment .

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

/**
 * Created by Kilnn on 2017/7/12.
 * A smart fragment know itself's visible state.
 */
public abstract class SmartFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean isFragmentVisible;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int switchType = getSwitchType();
        if (switchType == ATTACH_DETACH) {
            notifyOnFragmentVisible();
        } else if (switchType == SHOW_HIDE) {
            if (!isHidden()) {
                notifyOnFragmentVisible();
            }
        } else if (switchType == VIEW_PAGER) {
            //If the parent fragment exist and hidden when activity destroy,
            //when the activity restore, The parent Fragment  will be restore to hidden state.
            //And the sub Fragment which in ViewPager is also be restored, and the onResumed() method will callback.
            //And The sub Fragment's getUserVisibleHint() method will return true  if it is in active position.
            //So we need to judge the parent Fragment visible state.
            if (getUserVisibleHint() && isParentFragmentVisible()) {
                notifyOnFragmentVisible();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        int switchType = getSwitchType();
        if (switchType == VIEW_PAGER) {
            if (isVisibleToUser) {
                //If ViewPager in ViewPager , the sub ViewPager will call setUserVisibleHint before onResume
                if (isResumed()) {
                    notifyOnFragmentVisible();
                }
            } else {
                notifyOnFragmentInvisible();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        int switchType = getSwitchType();
        if (switchType == SHOW_HIDE) {
            if (hidden) {
                notifyOnFragmentInvisible();
            } else {
                //Just judge for safe
                if (isResumed()) {
                    notifyOnFragmentVisible();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        notifyOnFragmentInvisible();
    }

    private boolean isParentFragmentVisible() {
        Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        if (parent == null) return true;
        if (parent instanceof SmartFragment) {
            return ((SmartFragment) parent).isFragmentVisible();
        } else {
            //TODO May be can't get the correct visible state if parent Fragment is not SmartFragment
            return parent.isVisible();
        }
    }

    public boolean isFragmentVisible() {
        // Don't judge the state of the parent fragment,
        // because if the parent fragment visible state changes,
        // you must take the initiative to change the state of the sub fragment
//        return isFragmentVisible && isParentFragmentVisible();
        return isFragmentVisible;
    }

    public void notifyOnFragmentVisible() {
        if (!isFragmentVisible) {
            onFragmentVisible();
            isFragmentVisible = true;
        }
    }

    public void notifyOnFragmentInvisible() {
        if (isFragmentVisible) {
            onFragmentInvisible();
            isFragmentVisible = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * If this method callback, the Fragment must be resumed.
     */
    public void onFragmentVisible() {

    }

    /**
     * If this method callback, the Fragment maybe is resumed or in onPause().
     */
    public void onFragmentInvisible() {

    }

    /**
     * Fragments switch with attach/detach(replace)
     */
    public static final int ATTACH_DETACH = 0;

    /**
     * Fragments switch with show/hide
     */
    public static final int SHOW_HIDE = 1;

    /**
     * Fragments manage by view pager
     */
    public static final int VIEW_PAGER = 2;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @IntDef({ATTACH_DETACH, SHOW_HIDE, VIEW_PAGER})
    public @interface SwitchType {
    }

    @SwitchType
    public abstract int getSwitchType();

}
```

At last, hand the sub Fragment visible state in the parent Fragment if nested use.

```
public class ParentFragment extends SmartFragment{

    ....

    @Override
    public void onFragmentVisible() {
        super.onFragmentVisible();
        SmartFragment fragment = (SmartFragment) mAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.notifyOnFragmentVisible();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInvisible() {
        super.onFragmentInvisible();
        SmartFragment fragment = (SmartFragment) mAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.notifyOnFragmentInvisible();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

I have test with attach/detach, show/hide ,and three layers ViewPager nested. It work fine. Maybe I should have done more testing, but for me it was enough.