# How to know when fragment actually visible in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using 4 fragments inside a ViewPager ,as ViewPager load the previous and next fragment  in advance ,and no lifecycle   method is called when navigating between fragments.
So is there any way to detect when Fragment is actually visible.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. Assuming that `viewPager` is your instance of the `ViewPager`, use: `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`.

Within your `Fragment` you can check if its instance is visible to the user like so:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible) {
        Log.i("Tag", "Reload fragment");
    }
}
```

Always make sure that you search for answers throughly before asking your question. For instance, the first place you should check would be: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Thanks Matt .Actually I want to update the some view   when Fragment is visible ,so just looking for any callback method which is called every time when fragments is visible to user

Comment: Well you can create your own callback and, for example, call a method of the `viewPager` from within `setUserVisibleHint` of each one of your `Fragment` instances. If you want to update the same view, then this method itself is your answer. Just replace `Log.i()` with the code that you want to run each time the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: Be very careful: "this method may be called outside of the fragment lifecycle"

Comment: its only work with FragmentPagerAdapter !!! its not good

Answer (score 22):

as per @Matt's answer **`setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated**

so here is alternative way for this.

```
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean isvisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(isvisible);
        if (isvisible){
            Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is visible ");
        }else {
            Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is not visible ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JohnGlen which issue you have been face?

Comment: I thought if the Fragment was visible, that would mean it was rendered on screen. That was my misunderstanding.

Comment: @JohnGlen okay then you need to revert your downvote

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me till the answer is editied.

Comment: It is not working for Fragment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [viewPager.getCurrrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) to get the currently selected index, and from that you should be able to extrapolate which fragment is shown. However what you probably want is to use [addOnPageChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) to add an [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html).  This will let you keep track of what page is selected, as it's selected by implementing the [onPageSelected(int selected)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)) method.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [isVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#isVisible()) method in the fragment?

Comment: ViewPaget2 `isVisible` is helping to avoid additional calls when it is not a current fragment.

Comment: This does not work if you need to do stuff as soon as a Fragment is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can override `androidx.fragment.app.onResume` and `androidx.fragment.app.onPause`to detect if it is visible or not respectively.