# How to get previous destination with navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I have fragments A, B, C, and X where their navigations are as the following.

```
 A --> X 
 B --> X 
 C --> X
```

How could I know the information of the last or previous destination in X?

The current destination ID can be found by

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).getCurrentDestination().getId()
```

I also tried using `getBackStackEntry(int destinationId)` but it returns only the topmost NavBackStackEntry for a destination id. In other words, the current destination.

Also `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();` returning 0.

Possible solutions are:

1. Pass data from A, B, and C to X and identify the previous fragment by
   checking with that data.
2. Use shared SharedViewModel.

Is it possible to get the current destination?

Comment: why aren't you sending some parameters along with location so that you can know that location belongs to respective fragment.

Comment: Or you can know on which fragment you were on using these code and change your preference managers LastVistedFragment const see this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207043/check-if-fragment-is-currently-visible-or-no/43658331#43658331

Comment: Your solution is good but there should be something for getting backstack from a fragment. @SaiJayant

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? You want info from B to be in X ?

Comment: in pop backstack when you will be back to your previous fragment that method i told you also update the current showing fragment

Comment: I have not found any best solution to get the previous fragment in the currently visible fragment other than sending source id from A, B, and C to X. Thanks for the cooperation.

Answer (score 34):

Java: `Navigation.findNavController(v).getPreviousBackStackEntry().getDestination().getId();`

Kotlin:
`findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.id`

This should return you the previous destination's id in the 'X' fragment.

Comment: I think this will be null if popupTo is used, just fyi to others

Answer (score -3):

add destination change listener. and compare id with A,B,C of ids on back key press

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    // react on change or 
    //you can check destination.id or destination.label and act based on that
)}
```